# Keepalive timer on mqtt of nodemcu (esp8266) is not responding

Tags: lua, mqtt, keep-alive, esp8266, nodemcu

Dears, 
I am trying to use mqtt on esp8266 build on nodemcu. I am currently using a custom build (https://nodemcu-build.com/index.php)

modules used: adc,enduser_setup,file,gpio,http,mqtt,net,node,ow,pwm,tmr,uart,wifi

version:powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.1(e67da894)

```
function connect_to_mqtt_broker()


    print("Connecting to broker...")
    m:connect(BROKER, PORT, 0, 1, function(client) 
                                    print("connected") 
                                    print("["..tmr.time().."(s)] - Client connected to broker: "..BROKER)
                                    m:subscribe(SUB_TOPIC,0, function(conn) 
                                        print("Subscribed to "..SUB_TOPIC.." topic")
                                        led(0,204,0,150) 
                                    end)
                                    m:publish(PUB_TOPIC,"Hello from: "..node.chipid()..RESTART_REASON,0,0, function(conn) 
                                        print("sent")
                                    end)
                                  end, 
                                  function(client, reason) 
                                    print("failed reason: "..reason)
                                  end)

end
```

---

```
---MQTT client---
print("--------------> Create mqtt clinet")
--set up MQTT client
-- init mqtt client with keepalive timer 120sec
m = mqtt.Client("ESP"..node.chipid(), KEEP_ALIVE_TMR, USER, PASSWORD)
m:lwt(PUB_TOPIC, "offline", 0, 0)
m:on("offline", function(conn) 
        print("["..tmr.time().."(s)] - Mqtt client gone offline")

end)
m:on("message", function(conn, topic, data) 
        --receive_data(data, topic)
        print("Data received: "..data) 
        led(200,50,50,30)
        receive_data(data, topic)
        led(0,204,0,150)
end)
```

So at the initialization of the of the program I am calling **connect_to_mqtt_broker()**, which is working perfectly and I can subscribe and publish to topics.

The problem is that the keepalive timer is not correct. Let me explain that with an example. I set KEEP_ALIVE_TMR = 120s and after the esp8266 connected successfully to mqtt broker I disabled the wifi on my router and start counting seconds. According to KEEP_ALIVE_TMR the offline event:

```
m:on("offline", function(conn) 
        print("["..tmr.time().."(s)] - Mqtt client gone offline")

end)
```

should fire exactly 120 seconds from the moment I have disable WiFi, but for some unknown reason this won't happen. Usually the event fires up about 10-15 minutes later. 
I am struggling to understand the reason of this delay with no success. 
Do you have any ideas why this strange thing happens?

Comment: Tried the answers below ?

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced with the same issue when `autoreconnect` flag was set. This flag breaks the run of offline event of connection between broker.

Try it without setting `autoreconnect`, whose default is 0 :

```
m:connect(BROKER, PORT, 0, function(client)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do your testing by turning your mqtt broker on/off, and it works. But not by switching your wifi connections, then it is the nodemcu's mqtt library problem.

I believe that there is no such mqtt offline/disconnect event on wifi disconnection. Here it is the workaround by add connection's watchdog.

```
tmr.alarm(1, 3000, 1, function()
  if wifi.sta.getip() == nil then
   --mark as mqtt restart needed
   restart = true
 else
   -- wifi reconnect detected then restart mqtt connections
   if restart == true then
     --reset flag, clean object, init for a new one
     restart = false
     m = nil
     mqtt_init()
     connect()
   end
 end
end)
```

[Here it is the full code example](https://gondogblegudug.wordpress.com/2016/12/05/nodemcu-reconnect-mqtt-on-wifi-autoconnect/)